# MySQL replication or Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: database, .net, mysql, synchronization

I'm developing a Windows Application (WPF) which works on multiple instances of the same MYSql database, and those databases need to be synced, I'm not sure which solution should I go for, MS Sync Framework or Mysql replication, for MS Sync Framework, I'm not sure if it works fine with MySql, plus, the solution doesn't seem to be updated since like 4 years and I can't find any clear thread on the internet showing how to bundle the two technologies, and for MySql replication I'm not sure if that would be easy and stright forward to use with .Net, which path should I follow ?